# How to detect the equivalent Windows code pages for UTF8 text

Tags: windows, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I have a printing/mailing system running on Windows XP which does not support the use of UTF8 in the mailing lists. I'd like to convert the code page of the mailing list to the appropriate Windows native equivalent. But from my understanding it is not one size fits all and depending on the locale the code page will vary, e.g. Hungary, Greece, Sweden, Germany, Russia etc. Not to mention Chinese Traditional and so on.

Is there a way to detect, say for one record where there should not be more than one code page needed, what the appropriate Windows code page is?

Comment: You can't just choose a code page at random, the version of Windows you're running will have a code page that it uses. Trying to use any other code page isn't likely to work.

Comment: You're right about the OS having a set code page. The idea is to get it working with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale and the given code page. If this only has to be done a 10 times in a couple days this will be workable.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest idea I can think of:

For each codepage X from the list of all supported codepages:

1. Take the original Unicode text
2. Convert it to the codepage X.
3. Convert it back.
4. Check if anything changed.
5. If it didn't, congratulations, this is the codepage to use.

I believe there might be some minor problems with this solution (some rare characters may not roundtrip yet will look the same), but for most situations it should be fine.

Also, it's pretty easy to stumble upon a text that will not fit into one legacy encoding, so you need to be prepared for that. You can choose that differs the least from the original.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use a conversion tool such as [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) to attempt conversion to a number of different character sets and see which one succeeds without error.  The "-c" option noted in the man page seems to imply that the default behavior is to exit with an error if the conversion cannot succeed. (I've used iconv before and it works well but it was almost always to convert from an old charset to UTF-8, not the other way around ;)  With this approach, you would just try a predefined list of character sets and see which one succeeds.

Proof of concept (Mac OS 10.10.3):

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (GNU libiconv 1.11)

$ if echo '☃' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1; then echo 'It worked'; else echo 'Did not work'; fi
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
Did not work

$ if echo 'é' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 > /tmp/out.txt; then echo 'It worked'; else echo 'Did not work'; fi; hexdump -C /tmp/out.txt
It worked
00000000  e9 0a                                             |..|
00000002
```

(And byte value E9 is correct per this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Comment: Looks like the different behavior is to garble the text it can't deal with. I am not sure if that will be consistent from encoding to encoding though. I may still have to go with the full round trip idea mentioned by @karol-s

Comment: Maybe a different version of iconv or something else awry?  See edited answer (added example) - definitely works for me.

Comment: This method does work. I'm using this and also doing the reverse iconv to utf8 and diff to original and the results are equivalent - though several windows encoding all succeed on same sample. I'll need to do some broader tests to establish a positive process but the method seem to be sufficient and will hopefully avoid needing to raster and compare bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Emails support base64 encoded text (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html):

```
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SSBoYXZlIGEgcHJpbnRpbmcvbWFpbGluZyBzeXN0ZW0=
```

So you can try to convert utf8 text to bytes and then convert to base64.